# New PHP facebook SDK getRequestForNextPage

Tags: php, facebook

I have no idea why the getRequestForNextPage(); doesnt work.

I use it like this:

```
$photoRequest = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/'.$albumId.'?fields=photos.limit(30){picture,created_time,id,updated_time,width,height,from,link}' );
    do{
        pretty_print($photoRequest);
        $response = $photoRequest->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        foreach($graphObject['photos']->data as $index => $photo){
            // work on photos
        }
    }while ($photoRequest = $response->getRequestForNextPage());
```

I know for certain theres more then 30 pictures on 2 of the albums i go through, yet it still shows only the first 30.

When I var_dump $photoRequest = $response->getRequestForNextPage() it always returns null..

Is this the way to use this method?

Comment: What happens if you remove this: fields=photos.limit(30)

Comment: i will try but if i want to limit the photos to 30 per request for better performances? does the getRequestForNextPage(); isnt viable when you limit the photos?

Comment: isnt working even when I removed the limit( and apparently the default limit is 24 :)

Comment: Make that request in Graph API Explorer, see if you get a `next` link there, and if so see if it actually delivers any data.